# iOS app badge icon set to 1 unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, 64-bit, badge

Is there any reason my app may have a badge icon set to "1"? The app registers to receive notifications, but I am certain that none have been sent.

Running iOS 8.1.2, using an iPhone 6+

Comment: Do a project-wide search for `applicationIconBadgeNumber` and see if you unintentionally set it anywhere. If your app does receive a notification with a badge increment, you need to make sure decrement as well. Just throwing out some ideas, I've never seen this issue before

Comment: Thanks chris, but I had the same idea. Only time I use applicationIconBadgeNumber is when I explicitly reset it to 0.